# With Roo 2.0 I don't find web.xml so how do I configure Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I have been a Spring developer for some time and I have tried Roo in the past, and read through the improvements to Roo in 2.0 I used it to build a Web Application that works fine...to a point.  But when I tried to find the web.xml applicationcontext.xml to let me override some of the Spring MVC classes and add Interceptor filters and handlers, I could not find web.xml what's up with that?  Do I have to push in everything at some point? If I do will web.xml suddenly appear, I doubt it.

Comment: You don't need a `web.xml` with newer Servlet API versions i.e. 3.0 and up.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 generates Spring Boot applications, so there aren't neither web.xml nor application-context.xml

To learn more about what's new in Spring Roo 2.0 read http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/2.0.0.RC1/reference/html/#getting-started-whatsNew

To learn about Spring Boot goals read http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-introducing-spring-boot

Hope it helps